# How to merge internal lists of a 2D list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples in a 2D list, and I want to merge the list inside the tuples which correspond to the same integer.

For example:

```
list1 = [(0, [1]), (1, [0]), (1, [3]), (1, [9]), (2, [1]), (2, [4]), (3, [5]), (8, [1])]
```

I want to get the following output:

```
output = [(0, [1]), (1, [0,3,9]), (2,[1,4]), (3,[5]), (8,[1])]
```

I tried to use list comprehension but I didn't get the expected output. Could anyone help me get the output?

(I can't use dictionary)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code you tried. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or code writing service, we're here to help with code that's already been written.

Comment: *(I can't use dictionary)* - please explain that.

Comment: "(I can't use dictionary)" Why, why can't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is sorted by first tuple element *(the key)* you can just iterate over source list and concatenate lists until key is the same. Code:

```py
sorted_list = [
    (0, [1]), (1, [0]), (1, [3]), (1, [9]),
    (2, [1]), (2, [4]), (3, [5]), (8, [1])
]
lst = []
for i in sorted_list:
    if lst and lst[-1][0] == i[0]:
        lst[-1][1].extend(i[1])
    else:
        lst.append(i)
```

If your data is not sorted, you can sort it before. Code:

```py
unsorted_list = [
    (8, [1]), (3, [5]), (2, [4]), (2, [1]),
    (1, [9]), (1, [3]), (1, [0]), (0, [1])
]
unsorted_list.sort()
lst = []
for i in unsorted_list:
    if lst and lst[-1][0] == i[0]:
        lst[-1][1].extend(i[1])
    else:
        lst.append(i)
```

Both variants will modify source list, but you can avoid it if you'll append a copy of element, not element itself. For sorted input code will be:

```py
sorted_list = [
    (0, [1]), (1, [0]), (1, [3]), (1, [9]),
    (2, [1]), (2, [4]), (3, [5]), (8, [1])
]
lst = []
for k, l in sorted_list:
    if lst and lst[-1][0] == k:
        lst[-1][1].extend(l)
    else:
        lst.append((k, l[:]))
```

For unsorted input we can create a sorted copy of source list and work with it:

```py
unsorted_list = [
    (8, [1]), (3, [5]), (2, [4]), (2, [1]),
    (1, [9]), (1, [3]), (1, [0]), (0, [1])
]
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)
lst = []
for i in sorted_list:
    if lst and lst[-1][0] == i[0]:
        lst[-1][1].extend(i[1])
    else:
        lst.append(i)
```

This is the simplest solution and the fastest. Here is test results *(lower is better)*:

```
balderman(sorted_list): 1.780111159
balderman(unsorted_list): 1.7589877340000002
mozway(sorted_list): 1.0863068500000002
mozway_sort(unsorted_list): 1.2763536279999999
olvin(sorted_list): 0.5608128269999995
olvin_sort(unsorted_list): 0.6723953750000007
olvin_keep_source(sorted_list): 0.6709458179999999
olvin_sort_keep_source(unsorted_list): 0.7308210260000001
```

Code I've used for tests is [here](https://tio.run/##3VbbjpswEH3PV1i8LEhpRJpWSlPlSxCySHG2VgAjY9qkVb89nRlzTcgmrLTSsn5h8Myx5xwfGfKT@amy1TrX5/Neq5RJI7RRKimYTHOlDXvWqsx3pxllVS50ZJSuk1CdPgsDmNksFnu2i5JY6DTK3EKV@ofwNjMG4yBOBduyAiAidv8eAz9ke1jlyGTGbOU/jyqTwkBh4AJizoLQozJ4wUJcJaQqnBQt1m7SJCgDC7XTOOQeMrjxdsvw2c/igPQyXER5LrLYxRiqbFdamFLTmpZmqv78jk59jlVN0Czr9jZAQr2JALWjhvmcaEPTpDXNUdLSCBuY1@NJEllEDd3VPc07J@P6ngWG3eY5HsY7ZUAuqVp7iYlKfskLp1X@aW0ih2wCXsDCKIvxGXyio0ZjyCtj1HlwhjgadIaEuOUhkkJcIWoTyWH7UN8DB2BfFpTwpkbnIETObWd3juQAbhlF43CPQ/IgARe3Djahd@9cbrOxL@1lViWncVqwNedZlArOccMnztMIGPMnu0h1qRuZCmloJtcyM67TvdaRNU9kYbyNM69qF/bR3hdOpw4lcdqM68PFDiTmzF1C5DfRqom@QdRFfG4QGH2haAXRV4rWNtsBhOw767wOd@@0l1kBEuVbh75wtSS1GA24U5@V6U7o7dLHYVX2huUqs0cF61VeSrZuBGhpt1I08nQhtY6X2lq9/cc161N4Q9Waj@r0HDbQ@oNCWeRolezHY7Luuk1ilGy0wAjt6v@F6RnsuvMHhSLgWIkm7q6bHMZo9ipvXfw2TNRnN1mM0q@zyKv81@viA3jxBT6jfTlC3PP5Pw).

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed that. Responding at too many places in parallel. Anyway, [rewritten](https://tio.run/##1VJda4MwFH33V1x8aQRXdG7QdfgX9qwUCW7GLUwTielYf73Lh6aCrGvLXnpfcsI9NznnJN1BfnCWbDoxDBWpgTdflKGe78UbCbYeqGp6CSnsCrOpuQAKlIGlWIYuWhtiySq97u7iYhcVkKZA1XqkjQeaflysybckrEJU4cBxSNOTxcS67DpDtTxB5F4w3fA8pzs7IfyTHNTmhTPypw86Klcj/y98KqtHX/W7n/yEHzm6Cc@2IxcPIa9zImGrlC/fQd2FMStbgrG@b4VxW1KG8UqfRNuOCwmStoRKzyrGWrEo2TtByeixE5RJ5E/fUEhS4Yb2Mtj64Ti8tgty8vwZTwfkHzsoCkEbCwHFCkUOJQ49KTSfuHcTGj0YlCj0aNDGdmcDBTzDbLtU7oeu26u0utSvBW9hSmdKxgzOuGzfvhKRxpEuG3awiCi73Yyyq0PKLk0pv92U8qtTys9PKRiGHw) :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy, it turned into code golf :D

Comment: Not really. At least that was not my intention. Intention was the speed improvement.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I've decided to make it simpler for understanding, as walrus or accessing by reference is kinda implicit ways for beginner. But anyway it's possible to add few percents to performance with little modifications and great that you've highlighted that.

Answer (score 1):

Without dict / itertools - just nested loop

```
list1 = [(0, [1]), (1, [0]), (1, [3]), (1, [9]), (2, [1]), (2, [4]), (3, [5]), (8, [1])]
keys = sorted({x[0] for x in list1})
lst = [(key,[]) for key in keys]
for e  in list1:
  for ee in lst:
    if ee[0] == e[0]:
      ee[1].append(e[1][0])
print(lst)
```

output

```
[(0, [1]), (1, [0, 3, 9]), (2, [1, 4]), (3, [5]), (8, [1])]
```

Comment: `sorted(list(set([(x[0]) for x in list1])))` is a very convoluted way of doing `sorted({x[0] for x in list1})`, at the very least, remove the superfluous call to `list` which isn't required for passing it to `sorted`

Comment: But who is going to take care of the duplicate keys? For now it is the `set`.

Comment: `sorted({x[0] for x in list1})` **uses a `set`**

Comment: Got it - just noticed the `{}`

Comment: Code was updated- thanks.

Comment: `keys = keys = ...` ?

Comment: [rewritten version](https://tio.run/##PY1BCoMwEEX3c4pZJiCitQVb8CQhi4IpDUoMSRCl9OzpZArZPWbe/9@f6b25YfQh59XG1OOESnQNql7LBkVP1FUaKt2ZLtUrdGUaiG5M4/@rYTFnpN64hWRm8TmoEV9bwAOtQ179Slhj4m2SG6UlC8RFKXkNwBfq3HXNPQDRUqwYrXWzOcQi6UZlympab5/eGzeLXQL4YF0S9JI5/wA)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
[(k, list(chain.from_iterable((e[1] for e in g))))
 for k,g in groupby(list1, lambda x: x[0])]
```

*NB. The code above assumes that the input is sorted on the first key of that the consecutive keys must be grouped together. If their is a chance that the keys are not sorted and they still must be merged, then add a sorting step: `groupby(sorted(list1, lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])`*

output:

```
[(0, [1]), (1, [0, 3, 9]), (2, [1, 4]), (3, [5]), (8, [1])]
```

Comment: *I can't use dictionary* - (taken from the post).. So I am not sure `itertools` is a good direction.

Comment: Also note, this may or may not behave the way the OP expects based on the order here... also, use `chain.from_iterable`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll add a note on the order, but in any case the behavior is easily changed with a sort step, regarding the `from_iterable` I think it's mostly a matter of taste, I often go for the shorter expansion

Comment: `list(chain.from_iterable((e[1] for e in g)))` => `[i for _, l in g for i in l]`

Comment: Also it won't work with unsorted input

Comment: `lambda x: x[0]` => `itemgetter(0)`